# Site to site VPN between 2x ASA 5505 (8.4) not working

Tags: vpn, cisco

I have 2 cisco ASA 5505's running v8.42. All is working fine (using NAT), but I can't get a site-to-site VPN to work.

I used the wizard in the ASDM with default settings (except for the peer addresses / PSK / local / remote networks, of course).

When I send a ping to the other ASA, the tunnel won't come up. I found some posts on the Internet mentioning that a NAT exemption has to be made, so I checked the box for this in the ASDM wizard (using the option "inside" for it). Still no results.

Please help

```
: Saved
:
ASA Version 8.4(2)
!
names
<<NOT NEEDED>>
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
!
interface Ethernet0/2
!
interface Ethernet0/3
!
interface Ethernet0/4
!
interface Ethernet0/5
!
interface Ethernet0/6
!
interface Ethernet0/7
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address ASA-Apeldoorn 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address <<NOT NEEDED>> 255.255.255.248
!
banner login =   UNAUTHORIZED ACCESS STRICTLY PROHIBITED!
banner login =
banner login =   We monitor and audit the usage of this system and all persons
banner login =   are hereby notified that use of this system constitutes to such
banner login =   monitoring and auditing. Unauthorized access or modification of
banner login =   any information stored on this system may result in criminal prosecution.
banner login =
banner login =   PLEASE DISCONNECT IMMEDIATELY!
ftp mode passive
clock timezone CEST 1
clock summer-time CEDT recurring last Sun Mar 2:00 last Sun Oct 3:00
dns server-group DefaultDNS
 domain-name aacckantoor.local
object network obj_any
 subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
object network AmsioLAN
 subnet 10.11.79.0 255.255.255.0
object network NETWORK_OBJ_192.0.2.0_24
 subnet 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_2
 network-object object Sinkhole
 network-object object Sinkhole2
object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_2 tcp
 port-object eq www
 port-object eq https
access-list inside_access_in extended permit tcp 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 any eq www
access-list inside_access_in extended permit tcp 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 any eq https
access-list inside_access_in extended permit tcp 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 any eq ftp
access-list inside_access_in extended permit tcp 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 any eq 3389
access-list inside_access_in extended permit udp 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 any eq domain
access-list inside_access_in extended permit udp 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 any eq ntp
access-list inside_access_in extended permit icmp 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 any
access-list inside_access_in extended permit tcp host 192.0.2.10 any eq smtp
access-list inside_access_in extended permit tcp 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 any eq 5721
access-list inside_access_in extended permit tcp 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 any eq imap4
access-list inside_access_in extended permit tcp 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 any eq 587
access-list inside_access_in extended permit tcp 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 any eq ldap
access-list inside_access_in extended permit tcp 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 any eq 465
access-list inside_access_in extended permit tcp 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 any eq 3101
access-list inside_access_in extended permit tcp 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 any eq 2121
access-list inside_access_in extended permit tcp 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 any eq 49152
access-list inside_access_in extended permit tcp 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 any eq 49652
access-list inside_access_in extended permit tcp 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 any range 49152 49652
access-list inside_access_in extended permit udp 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 any eq 5059
access-list inside_access_in extended permit udp 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 any eq 5058
access-list inside_access_in extended deny tcp 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 object-group DM_INLINE_NETWORK_2 object-group DM_INLINE_TCP_2
access-list outside_access_in extended permit tcp any any eq www
access-list outside_access_in extended permit tcp any any eq https
access-list outside_cryptomap extended permit ip 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 object AmsioLAN
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging trap debugging
logging asdm informational
mtu inside 1500
mtu outside 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
nat (inside,outside) source static NETWORK_OBJ_192.0.2.0_24 NETWORK_OBJ_192.0.2.0_24 destination static AmsioLAN AmsioLAN no-proxy-arp route-lookup
!
object network obj_any
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
access-group inside_access_in in interface inside
access-group outside_access_in in interface outside
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 84.35.88.249 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
aaa authentication enable console LOCAL
aaa authentication http console LOCAL
aaa authentication serial console LOCAL
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL
aaa authentication telnet console LOCAL
http server enable
<<NOT NEEDED>>
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart warmstart
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal DES
 protocol esp encryption des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal 3DES
 protocol esp encryption 3des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES
 protocol esp encryption aes
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES192
 protocol esp encryption aes-192
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256
 protocol esp encryption aes-256
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto map outside_map 1 match address outside_cryptomap
crypto map outside_map 1 set peer <<NOT NEEDED>>
crypto map outside_map 1 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA ESP-AES-128-MD5 ESP-AES-192-SHA ESP-AES-192-MD5 ESP-AES-256-SHA ESP-AES-256-MD5 ESP-3DES-SHA ESP-3DES-MD5 ESP-DES-SHA ESP-DES-MD5
crypto map outside_map 1 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256 AES192 AES 3DES DES
crypto map outside_map interface outside
crypto ikev2 policy 1
 encryption aes-256
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 10
 encryption aes-192
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 20
 encryption aes
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 30
 encryption 3des
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 40
 encryption des
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 enable outside
crypto ikev1 enable outside
crypto ikev1 policy 10
 authentication crack
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 20
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 30
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 40
 authentication crack
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 50
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 60
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 70
 authentication crack
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 80
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 90
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 100
 authentication crack
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 110
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 120
 authentication pre-share
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 130
 authentication crack
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 140
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 150
 authentication pre-share
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400

console timeout 0

dhcpd auto_config outside
!
threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
webvpn
group-policy GroupPolicy_91.200.51.22 internal
group-policy GroupPolicy_91.200.51.22 attributes
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 ikev2
username <<NOT NEEDED>>
tunnel-group <<NOT NEEDED>> type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group <<NOT NEEDED>> general-attributes
 default-group-policy GroupPolicy_91.200.51.22
tunnel-group <<NOT NEEDED>> ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
 ikev2 remote-authentication pre-shared-key *****
 ikev2 local-authentication pre-shared-key *****
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map
  inspect ftp
  inspect h323 h225
  inspect h323 ras
  inspect rsh
  inspect rtsp
  inspect esmtp
  inspect sqlnet
  inspect skinny
  inspect sunrpc
  inspect xdmcp
  inspect sip
  inspect netbios
  inspect tftp
  inspect ip-options
  inspect pptp
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context
no call-home reporting anonymous
Cryptochecksum:a653d78272a501e97c50b13ad2ffec99
: end
```

Comment: Can you provide your configuration details (with any sensitive information removed) from `show running-config`, and maybe also the output of `show crypto isakmp sa` on both sides right after you try to build the tunnel?  Check for any interesting/relevant log entries?

Comment: There you go. Big part of the config is now in the question. Show crypto isakmp sa says: 
There are no IKEv1 SAs

There are no IKEv2 SAs

Answer (score 2):

You'll need the NAT exemptions for the interesting traffic... If using the wizard on 8.4, that's the last item.

Comment: Yes I checked that option! It makes me choose an interface where to apply it on, i chose the inside interface. Is that the problem? Should i have chosen the outside interface?

Comment: I tried following http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6120/products_configuration_example09186a0080bb8500.shtml, still no result